# How to get handle event name on socket-io nodeJs

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am working on socket application. and Client emit some event and on the server I handle that event. I want to extract that emitted event from socket object or server. I parsed are socket object but there is nothing which I am looking for. FOR EXAMPLE:
user emit socket.emit('/user/list') on server and handle socket.on('/user/list').. I want to get '/user/list' from socket object. I parsed object but I can't found. If someone know how to get that. I will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Not clear what you want. When you handle an event in socket.io, be on server or client side, you do know which event you are handling (e.g. '/user/list') because you are in that event handler...

Comment: yes i know that....but i want to get it from requested client...socket object @marekful

Comment: Makes no sense... When you are at home and ask me to phone you, do you request me to tell where you are over the phone?